# Sitecore link url encoding (XSLT)

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I'm generating links to my items in xslt using the following code:

```
<sc:link select=".">
  <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('SomeField',.)" />
</sc:link>
```

Unfortunately the generated URLs contain spaces when the item names have spaces in them, instead of %20.
I'm hoping there is some setting I can tweak to fix this. Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I like my solution slightly better than Mark's.

I've added a public static method `public static string UrlPathEncode(string)` to a class that is added as an xsl extension class:

```
public static string UrlPathEncode(string url)
{
    return HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(url);
}
```

Add this to web.config:

```
<xslExtensions>
  <extension mode="on" type="MyProject.Xsl.XslHelper, MyProject"
    namespace="http://www.myproject.net/sc" singleInstance="true" />
  ..
```

Add a reference to the xslt file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:mp="http://www.myproject.net/sc"
  ..
```

Now you can use the UrlPathEncode function like this:

```
<a href="{mp:UrlPathEncode(sc:path(.))}">
  <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('SomeField',.)" />
</a>
```

Not really an elegant solution, but it does encode every character that is disallowed in URL paths.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use Sitecores encodeNameReplacers.

Find that section in web.config and add:

```
<replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />
```

More info here: http://sitecoreninja.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/replace-space-with-dash-in-url.html

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this makes items with an actual dash in it inaccessible. Sitecore translates dashes in the url back to space and hence won't consider the item with the dash (there's a solution for that that requires some code). But if you put replaceWith="%20" the solution works. I was hoping for a more generic solution.
If I can't find a better solution, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "translate" function:

```
<sc:link select=".">
    <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('SomeField',translate(., ' ', '-'))"/>
</sc:link>
```